# Making of C++ DLL: static variable initialization problem

Tags: c++, oop, dll

I'm trying to make a DLL in C++, which I could use in other projects. 
One of my classes look like this

MyClass.h:

```
#ifdef MYDLL_EXPORTS
#define MYDLL_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define MYDLL_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

template <typename T, typename C>
class MYDLL_API MyClass
{
    private:
      static C *variable;

    //...
};
```

MyClass.cpp:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "MyClass.h"

template <typename T, typename C>
C *MyClass<T, C>::variable= NULL;
```

And when I compile it I get "error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ..." for this variable. 
This code has worked perfectly before I tryed to make DLL...

Please, help me fix this.

Comment: Did you define MYDLL_EXPORTS in your compiler command line (usually '-DMYDLL_EXPORTS')?

Comment: I need more context. Are you compiling the DLL and linking to it using the same compiler? Are you interfacing C code with C++ code?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot put the template class into DLL, since that simply will not work that way: the actual code for a class is emitted by compiler when you specify actual types for a template (that's why STL is shipped as source code).

Just create an .h file and add all implementation there. In other project, include it:

```
// MyClass.h
template <typename T, typename C>
class MyClass
{
    private:
       static C *variable;

    //...
};

template <typename T, typename C>
   C *MyClass<T, C>::variable= NULL;


// OtherProject.cpp
#include "MyClass.h"
// ...
MyClass<int, char> instance;  //...
```

If you know for sure, which types other project will use, you can use explicit instantiation, just add something like:

```
// explicitly instantiate class
template class MyClass<int, char>;
```

into MyClass.cpp